# How to convert from an 'hermite' curve into bezier curve?

Tags: c#, wpf, math, xna, bezier

As the topic states: How to convert from an Hermite curve into Bezier curve? Specifically I'm looking for a way to convert the Curve class, that uses Hermite interpolation, of the Microsoft XNA Framework to be drawn with StreamGeometry or PathGeometry of Windows Presentation Foundation.

I've come across a similar question ([Drawing Hermite curves in OpenGL) where the answer is the following.

```
[b0] = 1 [ 3  0  0  0] [h0]
[b1]   - [ 3  0  1  0] [h1]
[b2]   3 [ 0  3  0 -1] [v0]
[b3]     [ 0  3  0  0] [v1]
```

Which simplifies to:

```
b0 = h0
b1 = h0 + v0/3
b2 = h1 - v1/3
b3 = h1
```

Even with this information I'm in essence stuck on computing the control points. The Problem is that Curve class exposes a TangentIn and TangentOut as a scalar. Given that drawing of the polynomial occurs in 2-dimensional space (time, value) this scalar needs to be converted into a 2-dimensional vector in order to apply it to that formula. However I'm unsure what the steps are involved of this conversion process but I suspect I need to apply the Hermite differentiation equation.

If it helps this is the code used to evaluate the curve at a given moment as found with Reflector.

```
private static float Hermite(CurveKey k0, CurveKey k1, float t)
{
     if (k0.Continuity == CurveContinuity.Step)
     { 
         if (t >= 1f)
         {
             return k1.internalValue;
         }
         return k0.internalValue;
     }

     float num = t * t;
     float num2 = num * t;
     float internalValue = k0.internalValue;
     float num5 = k1.internalValue;
     float tangentOut = k0.tangentOut;
     float tangentIn = k1.tangentIn;
     return ((((internalValue * (((2f * num2) - (3f * num)) + 1f)) + (num5 * ((-2f * num2) + (3f * num)))) + (tangentOut * ((num2 - (2f * num)) + t))) + (tangentIn * (num2 -  num)));
}
```

Any information is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used XNA, but having glanced at the documentation it seems that the Curve class corresponds to a one-dimensional Bezier curve.  The conversion formula you quote should work fine: the "coordinates" in a one dimensional Bezier curve are all scalars.

Hence it doesn't really make sense to try to plot a single XNA Curve as a two-dimensional Bezier curve.  The Curve time value corresponds to the Bezier parameter t, not one of the spatial axes.

As it says in the Curve class documentation: "To represent a time path in two or three dimensions, you can define two or three Curve objects, each of which corresponds to a different spatial axis."

i.e. you need two Curve objects, one to provide the x value and one to provide the y value at a particular time.

Comment: @phr34k: I'm not sure if I inadvertently edited your comment instead of adding a new one or if you deleted it.  Anyway, you asked how to plot time versus value: use the value of the Curve you've got as the y coordinate.  Imagine you have another Curve whose value is simply the time parameter and use this for the x coordinate.  You now have two Curves and hence two sets of positions and tangents to parameterize your two-dimensional Bezier curve.

Comment: I think you misunderstood to actual goal. It's not about expressing a curvature in two dimensions for that I would need two curve objects as you stated. But rather to visualize the actual curvature. Or more specifically said to monitor how an variable with that curvature applied mutates over time. As reference see: http://tinyurl.com/5w3q5mz

Most common way to achieve this would be using discrete sampling i.e. at each point in time evaluate the value and simply draw a line between all adjacent samples. But I would prefer to convert the polynomial itself

Comment: Yeah sorry I deleted the first comment to update it. Didn't expect Enter to automatically post the comment.

Comment: As I said, if you create a second Curve x(t)=t and use the first curve as y(t) then the resulting Bezier will be value against time for the first curve, as required.

Comment: @arx The resulting bezier should be an array of control points, namely a `Vector[]`:  `(x(t0), y(t0))`, `(x(t1), y(t1))`, .... What kind of *t0,t1,...* values should I use?